# Java の JPanel this.panel = panel と this.panel.add(panel) の違いは？

Tags: java, swing, gui

下のメソッドは、引数として渡された `JPanel` を `Main` クラスのフィールド `panel` に設定するというものなのですが、①と②どちらが正しいのでしょうか？
私的には①が正しいと思っていたのですが、フレームに追加した際表示されたのは②のやり方だけでした。

例示のメソッドはかなり簡略化しているのですが、実際は他クラスAの `getPanel()` メソッドを引数に渡しています。Aで `panel` にコンポーネントを追加して、それを `add(panel)` という形で表示させたいです。

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
//フィールド、コンストラクタ、他のメソッド
//
   private void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
      this.panel = panel;    //①
     
      this.panel.add(panel); //②
   }
//
//他のメソッド
}
```

Comment: Mainクラスの中でthis.panelはどのように初期化していますか。

Answer (score 2):

> 下のメソッドは、引数として渡された `JPanel` を `Main` クラスのフィールド `panel` に設定するというものなのですが、①と②どちらが正しいのでしょうか？

ここだけを切り取れば、正しいのは①です。

ただ、①がやっているのはSwingは無関係で、

```java
public class MyClass {
    private int number;
    
    private void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

こういうコードと同じです。
つまり「フィールド `number`(質問文のコードなら `panel`) に設定した値はなにかに使うつもりなんだろうけど、何に使うの？」という状態です。

画面に表示するためにはトップレベルコンテナーが持つコンテナー階層に追加する必要があります。
要するに②のような`add()`する操作が必要です。

[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/98911/2808) と合わせて推測するに、やりたいことは次のようなものではないかと考えます(実際には①も②も必要):

```java
public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;

    private void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
        remove(this.panel);

        // ①
        // 次回setPanel()を呼んだときにremoveするために
        // 引数のパネルをpanelフィールドに保持する
        this.panel = panel;

        // ②
        // 引数のパネルを表示
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        validate();
    }
}
```

動くサンプルコードはこちら:

```java
package com.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private final JButton topButton;

    private JPanel panel;

    public Main() {
        super("Main");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        topButton = new JButton("Refresh");
        topButton.addActionListener(this::onTopButtonClick);
        add(topButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panel = newCenterPane();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    private void onTopButtonClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        var newPane = newCenterPane();
        setPanel(newPane);
    }

    private void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
        remove(this.panel);

        // ①
        // 次回setPanel()を呼んだときにremoveするために
        // 引数のパネルをpanelフィールドに保持する
        this.panel = panel;

        // ②
        // 引数のパネルを表示
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        validate();
    }

    private static JPanel newCenterPane() {
        var panel = new JPanel();
        var label = new JLabel(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
        panel.add(label);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            var frame = new Main();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```