# JavaのJPanelが更新されない

Tags: java, swing, gui

スプラトゥーン3のスケジュール情報を[Spla3 API](https://spla3.yuu26.com/)というサイトから取得し、その情報を表示するというGUIをJavaで作成しています。

以下のコード`SplaScheduleGui`は`JFrame`を継承して、コンポーネントの初期化とフレームへの追加をしています。
`BorderLayout`を使用してフレームの上部（`Borderayout.NORTH`）にボタンをセットしたパネル、中央（`Borderayout.CENTER`）に押されたボタンのスケジュール情報をセットしたパネル、下部（`Borderayout.SOUT H`）に現在どのスケジュールを表示しているかを表す文字列（例　「レギュラーマッチ」など）を表示するようにしています。

例えば、フレーム上部のレギュラーマッチのボタンを押すと、中央にレギュラーマッチのスケジュールが、下部に現在レギュラーマッチのスケジュールを表示していることを知らせるため「レギュラーマッチ」が表示されるのですが、バンカラマッチのボタンを押しても「バンカラマッチ」とは表示されず「レギュラーマッチ」のままで、パネルが更新されません。
原因はどこでしょうか。

```
public class SplaScheduleGui extends JFrame {
    private JButton regularButton;
    private JButton bankaraButton;
    private JButton xButton;
    private JButton eventButton;
    private JButton festButton;
    private JButton salmonRunButton;
    private JPanel lobbyPanel; // ロビー情報（レギュラーバトル、バンカラマッチ、Xマッチなど）を表示するパネル、フレーム下部に表示
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public SplaScheduleGui() {
        super("Splatoon3 Schedule App");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        initButton();
        initPanel();
        initScrollPane();
        addGuiComponents();
        setActionListenerToButton();
    }

    private void initScrollPane() {
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
    }

    private void addGuiComponents() {
        add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(lobbyPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        lobbyPanel = new L_RegularPanel();
    }

    private void setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(JPanel schedulePanel, JPanel lobbyPanel) {
        scrollPane.setViewportView(schedulePanel);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(lobbyPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void onRegularButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(new RegularPanel(), new L_RegularPanel());
    }

    private void onBankaraButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(new BankaraPanel(), new L_BankaraPanel());
    }

    private void onXButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(new XPanel(), new L_XPanel());
    }

    private void onEventButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(new EventPanel(), new L_EventPanel());
    }

    private void onFestButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(new FestPanel(), new L_FestPanel());
    }

    private void onSalmonRunButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(new SalmonRunPanel(), new L_SalmonRunPanel());
    }

    private void setActionListenerToButton() {
        regularButton.addActionListener(this::onRegularButtonClick);
        bankaraButton.addActionListener(this::onBankaraButtonClick);
        xButton.addActionListener(this::onXButtonClick);
        eventButton.addActionListener(this::onEventButtonClick);
        festButton.addActionListener(this::onFestButtonClick);
        salmonRunButton.addActionListener(this::onSalmonRunButtonClick);
    }

    private void initButton() {
        regularButton = new LobbyButton("src/assets/regular.png");
        bankaraButton = new LobbyButton("src/assets/bankara.png");
        xButton = new LobbyButton("src/assets/x.png");
        eventButton = new LobbyButton("src/assets/event.png");
        festButton = new LobbyButton("src/assets/fest.png");
        salmonRunButton = new LobbyButton("src/assets/salmonrun.png");
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 10));
        buttonPanel.add(regularButton);
        buttonPanel.add(bankaraButton);
        buttonPanel.add(xButton);
        buttonPanel.add(eventButton);
        buttonPanel.add(festButton);
        buttonPanel.add(salmonRunButton);
        return buttonPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            SplaScheduleGui scheduleGui = new SplaScheduleGui();
            scheduleGui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

[image: バンカラマッチのスケジュールが表示されているが、下部のパネルには「レギュラーマッチ」と表示されている様子]

Answer (score 1):

`setScheduleAndLobbyPanels()` で用いている [`add()` の JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object)) を見てみると次のようにあります:

> コンテナがすでに表示されている場合は、追加されたコンポーネントを表示するために、あとで階層を検証する必要があります。

「検証する」というのは、このドキュメントの他の箇所も読めばわかりますが、 [`validate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#validate()) を呼び出すことです。つまり、

```java
    private void setScheduleAndLobbyPanels(JPanel schedulePanel, JPanel lobbyPanel) {
        scrollPane.setViewportView(schedulePanel);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(lobbyPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        validate();
    }
```

とすれば追加した `lobbyPanel` を表示できます。

が、本来ここでやりたいことは、前回追加したコンポーネントを除去(`remove()`)した上で、新しいコンポーネントを追加(`add()`)し直すことではないかなと思います。
(現状の実装だと、ボタンを押すたびにコンポーネントが重なっていくと思います)